# Javascript event listener to ArrowDown - Stop page scrolling

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have a hopefully rather simple Javascript question for you. I have a scrollable, static page which can show/hide a full frame overlay (hiding the whole page) using z-index. When the overlay is shown I create a new event listener to "keydown" in which I for example check for "ArrowDown". When the overlay is hidden, the listener is unsubscribed.

This works beautifully, except that the page below the overlay keeps scrolling up and down as it normally would. I thought I could stop that by using

```js
event.stopPropagation()
```

which, however, does not help. How can I approach this?

Comment: this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily

Comment: event.preventDefault() should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event.stopPropagation()` Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM, but **does not stop the browsers default behaviour**.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

this should work **as it stops the browsers default behaviour**.

Comment: Hm I thought I also tried that already. Let me check again. Edit: Thanks very much, I must have been mistaken - that works beautifully!